# How to call if statement between two hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, react-hooks

In my project, i am using useState & useEffect to fetch data from API. Now suppose, based on my scenario, i am having 2 API to fetch data. 1st API using to get id and using id to fetch 2nd API.

as you all know to fetch API using useEffect some cases, 1st render it's giving undefine and the it's given data, so i try to use if statement to avoid undefined to avoid 1st API's undefined. but while i use 2 hooks in one project, i can't able to use that if statement after 1st hooks. if i use it end of both hooks, if statement is not work properly.
In that case, where should i use if statement while i use 2 hooks in one project. where if statement for 1st hooks to work.

suppose, my codes here:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import View from 'react-native';


export default function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      'https://www.roads.com/road/api/auth/web/roadControl?projectId=765&pageSize=150')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.id))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  if (!data) return null;

  async function fD() {
    try {
      const rA = await Promise.all(
        data?.map((id) => {
          const nfo= fetch(`https://www.roads.com/road/web/roadControl/${id}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((a) => {
              return a;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
          return nfo;
        })
      );
      setLoc(rA);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fD();
  });
}
```

In this case where should i use the if statement for the 1st hooks to use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzL95.png)

Comment: You don't need the `data` state when you can directly call `fD` in the first `useEffect` hook. What is the value of `data.id` that is stored in the `data` state? In the first `useEffect` hook it seems to be updated to a single id value, but in the `fD` function it seems to be an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try putting `fD()` inside the then block in the `useEffect` hook instead. In fact, I don't think the `useState` hook is needed for storing data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      'https://www.roads.com/road/api/auth/web/roadControl?projectId=765&pageSize=150')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => fD(id) // passing id to the function as parameter)
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, i was asking at the top how can i use if statement between two hooks in a project, if condition will be for first hooks.